# Installation using 2 SSD's

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on a i7-8565U @1.8GHz and 20GB RAM with 2 SSD's: 1 nvme and 1 SSD. What's the best setup regarding these 2 disks? I don't want to dual boot.

I am thinking of using the nvme for boot / root / swap and the SSD for `/home`. Is that ok?

Comment: That is exactly my configuration. Of course it also depends on the size of the disks and your intended usage pattern.

Comment: Using the NVMe for boot and system while the SSD is used for `/home` is certainly what I would go with for a daily driver, but it's just an opinion. There are certainly use cases where you might go with something very different ... particularly if you're doing a bunch of database work or things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both drives are solid state drives, and the NVMe SSD is the faster of the two drives. NVMe SSDs currently run in the 256GB/512GB/1TB size range. Depending on the size of the SSDs, you can install everything in a single partition on the NVMe SSD and [split the home directory into two different partitions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104515/) or use the 2nd SSD for data storage.

Comment: I keep /home inside / on NVMe drive and have HDD for all the folders & data normally in /home. I also move some hidden folders like Firefox & Thunderbird profiles to data partition also. Primarily as I have multiple Ubuntu installs and want same data, but not configuration as testing or experimenting and do not want to change main working install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk